# How to vertically align top line of multiline Text and Button title with Toggle label, in Hstack?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, text-alignment

I have the following code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isOn: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .top) {
            Toggle(isOn: $isOn) {
                Text("Hello")
            }

            Text("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog")

            Spacer()

            Button("Go") {
                print("Knock knock.")
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Which results in:

[image: Result]

How do I vertically align the top line: `The quick brown fox` and `Go` with desiredly positioned `Hello`?

Of course I can manually tune the alignment with hard-coded `.offset()`; I have this now in my code.  But that's ugly and will fall apart if I'd change the font size(s) for example.  I'm looking for a proper method without hard-code values.

Isn't this possible with SwiftUI alignment features?

Comment: Show desired alignment image and the current layout

Comment: @meaning-matters - I think you *do* need to show us what you're getting... here's what I get with your code ***without the `.offset(...)`***: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFCMW.png --- looks aligned to me.

Comment: @DonMag I have also checked the code Button and Text are aligned but the toggle button is slightly upward: [https://imgur.com/a/Am2Z8zH](https://imgur.com/a/Am2Z8zH) I think he is asking about toggle button ?

Comment: @QaziAmmar - the OP added an offset to the `Button` …

Comment: I have removed the `.offset(...)` to button.

Comment: @QaziAmmar - because the OP says he is trying to offset the Button, it's not clear what he is trying to align. Here's a better image to discuss -- background colors, so we can see the ***framing*** alignment, and a red line to show the text alignment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2LzW.png

Comment: @DonMag Yea you are right, question is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach (the Toggle button toggles background colors on/off):

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var isOn: Bool = false

    @State var c1: Color = Color(red: 1.00, green: 0.75, blue: 0.75)
    @State var c2: Color = Color(red: 0.75, green: 1.00, blue: 0.75)
    @State var c3: Color = Color(red: 1.00, green: 1.00, blue: 0.00)
    @State var c4: Color = Color(red: 0.80, green: 1.00, blue: 0.75)
    @State var c5: Color = Color(red: 0.75, green: 0.75, blue: 0.25)
    
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack(alignment: .top) {
                
            Spacer()
            
            Toggle(isOn: $isOn) {
                Text("Hello")
                    .background(isOn ? c1 : .clear)
            }
            .background(isOn ? c2 : .clear)
            .offset(CGSize(width: 0.0, height: -5.0))
            
            Text("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog")
                .background(isOn ? c3 : .clear)
                
            Spacer()
            
            Button("Go") {
                print("Knock knock.")
            }
            .background(isOn ? c4 : .clear)
            
            Spacer()
            
        }
        .background(isOn ? c5 : .clear)
        .padding()
        
    }

}
```

Output (red line is added after, to show the text baselines):

[image]

You would probably want to use GeometryReader to calculate the correct offset, rather than using the hard-coded `y: -5.0`

---

**Edit** -- *after quick searching for dynamic sizing instead of hard-coded `y: -5.0`*

Based on info found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63050004/6257435

Looks like custom `.alignmentGuide` is what you need:

```
import SwiftUI

extension VerticalAlignment {
    private enum XAlignment : AlignmentID {
        static func defaultValue(in d: ViewDimensions) -> CGFloat {
            return d[VerticalAlignment.top]
        }
    }
    static let xAlignment = VerticalAlignment(XAlignment.self)
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var isOn: Bool = true

    @State var c1: Color = Color(red: 1.00, green: 0.75, blue: 0.75)
    @State var c2: Color = Color(red: 0.75, green: 1.00, blue: 0.75)
    @State var c3: Color = Color(red: 1.00, green: 1.00, blue: 0.00)
    @State var c4: Color = Color(red: 0.80, green: 1.00, blue: 0.75)
    @State var c5: Color = Color(red: 0.75, green: 0.75, blue: 0.25)
    
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack(alignment: .xAlignment) {

            Spacer()
            
            Toggle(isOn: $isOn) {
                Text("Hello")
                    .background(isOn ? c1 : .clear)
            }
                .background(isOn ? c2 : .clear)
                .alignmentGuide(.xAlignment) { $0.height * 0.5 }
            
            Text("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog")
                .background(isOn ? c3 : .clear)
                .alignmentGuide(.xAlignment) {
                    ($0.height - ($0[.lastTextBaseline] - $0[.firstTextBaseline])) * 0.5
                }

            Spacer()
            
            Button("Go") {
                print("Knock knock.")
            }
            .background(isOn ? c4 : .clear)
            .alignmentGuide(.xAlignment) { $0.height * 0.5 }

            Spacer()

        }
        .background(isOn ? c5 : .clear)
        .padding()

    }

}
```

Comment: Of course I can manually tune the alignment with hard-coded `.offset()`; I have this now in my code.  But that's ugly and will fall apart if I'd change the font size(s) for example.  I'm looking for a proper method without hard-code values.

Isn't this possible with SwiftUI alignment features?

Comment: @meaning-matters - see the **Edit** to my answer.

Comment: Great, thanks!  Just wondering, why did you use the letter X in identifiers for vertical alignment?

Comment: @meaning-matters - I based it on what I found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63050004/6257435

Answer (score -1):

[Updated]

If you want to align vertically then you need to change your Hstack Alignment from .center to .top. From image below you can see toggle Text and Text are align horizontally.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var isOn: Bool = false

      var body: some View {
          HStack(alignment: .top) {
              HStack(alignment: .top) {
                  Text("Hello")
                  Toggle(isOn: $isOn) {
                      
                  }
              }

              Text("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog")

              Spacer()

              Button("Go") {
                  print("Knock knock.")
              }
              .padding()
          }
          .padding()
      }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I want the top line: `The quick brown fox`, to be aligned with `Hello`.

Comment: Now the button title `Go` is not aligned yet.

Comment: You have assign padding to the button if you remove the padding of the button then it will be alight with others.